# Use Laplace transform to solve $xy”+(1-x)y’+my=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Use Laplace transform to solve $xy''+(1-x)y'+my=0$.

(a) $y=\displaystyle\frac{e^t}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dt^k}(t^{-k}e^{-t})$

(b) $y=\displaystyle\frac{e^t}{k} \frac{d^k}{dt^k}(t^k e^{-t})$

(c) $y=\displaystyle\frac{e^t}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dt^k}(t^k e^{-t})$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please be aware that this is not a homework working service. Please explain your thoughts on the problem and what difficulties you are having finding the solution and perhaps someone will be willing to help you sort it out.

Comment: What is $k$?  Did you mean $m$?  $k$ can't for sure be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(x f(x)\right) = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\left(f(x)\right)
$$

then

$$
-\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\left(\ddot y\right)+\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\left(\dot y\right)+\mathcal{L}\left(\dot y\right)+m\mathcal{L}\left(y\right)=0
$$

with

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\ddot y\right) = s^2Y(s)-\dot y(0)-s y(0)\\
\mathcal{L}\left(\dot y\right) = sY(s)-y(0)\\
$$

and then solve the $Y(s)$ DE.

NOTE

After deriving we get at

$$
Y'(s)(s-s^2) + (m+1-s)Y(s) = 0
$$

with solution

$$
Y(s) = C_0 \frac{(1-s)^m}{s^{m+1}}
$$

Comment: So is it a, b, or c!!!! That's the real question.

Comment: @user14717 This is your attribution. See the attached note

Comment: @user14717  Cesareo gave a good hint, and that should have been sufficient for you to work it out.  If you had tried, then you would have seen that $$y(x)=\frac{\exp(x)}{m!}\,\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m}\,\big(x^m\,\exp(-x)\big)$$ is a solution.

Comment: Furthermore, if $\displaystyle f_m(x):=\frac{\exp(x)}{m!}\,\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m}\,\big(x^m\,\exp(-x)\big)$, then all solutions to the differential equation $$x\,y''(x)+(1-x)\,y'(x)+m\,y'(x)=0\,, \text{ where }m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\,,$$ takes the form $y(x)=A\,f_m(x)+B\,g_m(x)$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants, and $$g_m(x):=f_m(x)\,\int_1^x\,\frac{\exp(t)}{t\,\big(f_m(t)\big)^2}\,\text{d}t\,.$$

Comment: It was a joke, people.

Comment: The answer is d